# For how many customers was this the first-ever merchant they ordered with? SQL question

Tags: sql, postgresql, groupwise-maximum

I am struggling with this sql question:

For each merchant, find how many orders and first-time orders they had. First-time orders are meant from the perspective of a customer and are the first order that a customer ever made. In order words, for how many customers was this the first-ever merchant they ordered with?
Output the name of the merchant, the total number of their orders and the number of these orders that were first-time orders.

| orders |
| --- |
| id int |
| customer_id int |
| merchant_id int |
| order_timestamp datetime |
| n_items int |
| total_amount_earned float |

| merchants |
| --- |
| id int |
| name varchar |
| category varchar |
| order_timestamp datetime |
| zipcode int |

this is what i have so far:

```
with first_time_orders as (
  select customer_id, rank() over (partition by merchant_id order by order_timestamp) as first_order
  from orders
  group by customer_id, merchant_id
)

select *
from first_time_orders;
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with your issues, but there some expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com) and review [ask]. Specifically, post the actual table definition (ddl) script along with sample data, as text -**no images** (even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14) ) and the expected results of that data (also as text).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

with cter as
(select *,
dense_rank() over (partition by customer_id order by order_timestamp ) h
from doordash_orders)
select * from (select merchant_id,count(*) gb from cter group by merchant_id) h
join
(select merchant_id,count(*) gbb from cter where h=1 group by merchant_id) p
on h.merchant_id=p.merchant_id